# Is metadata api missing Record Type assignments in permission sets?

Tags: metadata, metadata-api

we have a use case to insert permissionsets dynamically and assign the right type of record types for objects of that particular permission set. does metadata api has the record type assignment type for permission sets?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? You need to dynamically assign rights to various record types?

Comment: I am trying to create a permission set using metadata api. in permission sets we have the record type assignment. so i am trying to assign some recordtypes to the permission set. but unfortunately in the metadata api developer guide i do not see a metadata type for the recordtype assignments in permission sets.

Answer (score 2):

It is avaiable in API v29.0 ,  please refer to details of http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_permissionset.htm

Answer (score 1):

While record types are supported on permission sets, they are not yet supported in the Metadata API (MdAPI). The same is true of assigned apps which are supported on permission sets but not yet in the MdAPI. Please stay tuned for when we do provide this support. Thanks!