# How do I distribute Record Type Assignments when packaging Permission Sets?

Tags: managed-package, metadata-api, profile, record-type, postinstall

I'm trying to create a Managed Package that relies entirely on Permission Sets. No profiles!

In my head, Profiles are really "owned" by each org administrator. One needs *serious* justification to hijack the one-and-only bite at the cherry and expect package installors to reassign user profiles. The great thing about Permission Sets is they are "owned" by the vendor and allow the admin to enrich and decorate accordingly. But that's enough about my perception of good platform citizenship :-)

Here's what the Permission Set looks like in the packaging / release org:

[image: package]

But here's how it looks installed into another organization: (**no assignments, no edit button!!!**)

[image: install]

Here's what I can fathom so far:

- this is similar to the [widely](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/1325/320) [reported](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/23194/320) loss of Custom App visibility
- the [Metadata API cannot assign record types](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/13766/320) so one can't automate a post-install mechanism
- nobody is going to use a packaged custom profile just for my shitty little app

So in the interests of best practise: **how, today, should we package Record Type Assignments**?

Comment: I get the impression from [Record Type Selection in Permission Sets](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000avCuAAI) that the record type selection should work in a Permission Set.

Comment: As a sub-optimal "solution", the Managed Permission Set can be cloned in Customer's Org and Configuration left to Customer's Administrator as part of the Installation process... suboptimal.

Comment: @DanielBallinger I'm struggling here... it seems like the assigned RTs are silently dropped when the package is installed, much like visibility of custom apps.

Comment: @bigassforce It does seem that way, doesn't it. I was just going off the notes in that idea that it *should* work. Maybe try a support case?

Comment: @DanielBallinger [JOKE] In the link you posted, SF guy states: "AFAIK the feature is working". I'm just guessing if "AFAIK" is the more readable version (or the product team version) of the well known Safe Harbour. [/JOKE] Anyway, I hope it sorts out positively and you were right, I'll keep an eye here because it would be something useful to know for me too, since I work principally on managed applications.

Comment: Good point @DanielBallinger - opened Case Number 11205684

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bah. You can't. Salesforce have now documented their way out of this one ;-)

> Best Practices
>
> If users need access to apps, tabs, page layouts, and record types, **don't use permission sets** as the sole permission-granting model for your app. Assigned apps and tab settings are available in the permission set user interface, but they aren’t included in permission set package components.

[salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_perm_sets_profile_setttings](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_perm_sets_profile_setttings.htm)

So: Record Types are destined for the domain of the installor, not the packagor. The the same way as Profiles are owned by each org administrator and should be extended by Permission Sets.

Comment: The More You Know™...

Comment: 2019 and this is still not possible in Salesforce :(

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this became available a few days ago. Salesforce had a bug that record type assignments in permission sets were not working in packages for years but this was fixed. I was not able to find any information in the official release notes or anywhere else but we had to open a Case and they said that this is now fixed.